# Error while stopping windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am working on Windows Service. It works fine. When i am trying to stop the service from `services.msc`, it throws the following error:

> Windows could not stop the xxx service on Local Computer.
>   The service did not return an error.  This could be an internal Windows error or an internal service error.
>   If the problem persists, contact your system administrator.

If I try to stop it again, it takes lots of time and then throws the error as below:

> Windows could not stop the xxx service on Local Computer.
>   Error 1061: The service cannot accept control messages at this time.

At this point, the service has stopped. But if I try to reinstall the service, it throws another error:

> Windows could not stop the xxx service on Local Computer.
>   Error 1001: The specified service is marked for deletion.

After closing `services.msc`, it lets me reinstall the service and again things start working fine.

In `OnStop()`, I am doing some lengthy operations and it takes time to complete.

Any idea how I can make the whole thing go smoothly?

--Edit--

This is what my `OnStop` method looks like:

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
    base.OnStop();
    //Some lengthy operation      
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The windows service have a default timeout in onstart and onstop events. Normally if you are **doing time consuming operations** in any of these events **start a new thread and let the operation to perform in background**.

**Usually the OnStart as well as OnStop events within the windows service are used to initiate a process and the time consuming process will carryout it's execution within a child thread**.

Hope this will solve your issue..

Comment: We just stop some tasks in OnStop method using cancellation token source. Can tasks (from task parallel library) also result in long time to get stopped by .Net runtime?

Answer (score 2):

There is a registry entry that controls how much time windows gives services to shut down before giving up: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/146092

Trivially, increasing this time would fix the issue, assuming that your service is actually shutting down after that long operation.

Comment: cant ask them to change the system configuration. Can i not specify that in my service?

Comment: I don't believe so.  What is the service doing that takes so long to finish?  Can that be optimized?

Comment: It actually is one line of code. I am subscribed to an external application which publishes the messages. All i am doing is unsubscribing from it. Unsubscribing from it takes a little long time.

Comment: That doesn't sound right.  If you are tearing down a client (stopping the service), I would bet that you don't need to formally unsubscribe.  The server should, in the worst case, detect that the TCP session has ended, and stop sending the messages (as I assume it would if the machine hosting your service crashed).

Comment: Server keeps track of who is subscribed and sends messages accordingly. If i dont unsubscribe, it doesnt let me subscribe again. Also i noticed that if i use UnInstaller, it works fine and doesnt raise any error. It stops the service and removed from the system.

Comment: I tried using base.RequestAdditionalTime(int.MaxValue); but no luck :(

Comment: You can edit registry strings in your installer if the problem is the said configuration. About how long, in seconds, does it take to unsubscribe?

Comment: takes around 20-30 seconds to unsubscribe